# Replacement for IpcChannel in .NET 5

Tags: c#, ipc, .net-5

I'm migrating my WPF .NET Framework 4.8 app to .NET 5.

I noticed that IpcChannel is missing from .NET 5.
I used it to pass arguments and execute code in another process when dealing with single instance behaviors.

Is there any simple replacement for my use case?

```cs
    /// <summary>
    /// Interprocess channel that is responsible for passing to another instance the parameters of this instance (in cases of when just one instance is allowed).
    /// </summary>
    public static class InstanceSwitcherChannel
    {
        internal static IpcChannel ServerChannel { get; private set; }
        
        
        internal static void RegisterServer()
        {
            try
            {
                if (ServerChannel != null)
                    return;

                ServerChannel = new IpcChannel("localhost:9192");
                System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.ChannelServices.RegisterChannel(ServerChannel, true);

                //Expose an object for remote calls.
                System.Runtime.Remoting.RemotingConfiguration.RegisterWellKnownServiceType(typeof(InterProcessRemoteObject), "AppRemoteObject.rem", System.Runtime.Remoting.WellKnownObjectMode.Singleton);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                //log...
            }
        }

        internal static void UnregisterServer()
        {
            try
            {
                if (ServerChannel == null)
                    return;

                System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.ChannelServices.UnregisterChannel(ServerChannel);

                ServerChannel = null;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                //log... 
            }
        }

        internal static void SendMessage(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                var channel = new IpcChannel();

                System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.ChannelServices.RegisterChannel(channel, true);

                //Register as client for remote object.
                var remoteType = new System.Runtime.Remoting.WellKnownClientTypeEntry(typeof(InterProcessRemoteObject), "ipc://localhost:9192/AppRemoteObject.rem");
                System.Runtime.Remoting.RemotingConfiguration.RegisterWellKnownClientType(remoteType);

                var service = new InterProcessRemoteObject();
                service.SendArguments(args);

                System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.ChannelServices.UnregisterChannel(channel);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                //log...
            }
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Object that is used as the inter process bag.
        /// </summary>
        public class InterProcessRemoteObject : MarshalByRefObject
        {
            /// <summary>
            /// Method used to receive arguments from another instance.
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="args">The arguments to be passed to the other instance.</param>
            public bool SendArguments(string[] args)
            {
                try
                {
                    if (args?.Length > 0)
                        Argument.Prepare(args);

                    //... Logic that should be executed in the target process.
                    //In this case, to open another window.

                    return true;
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    LogWriter.Log(e, "Impossible to send/receive arguments via IPC.");
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/porting/net-framework-tech-unavailable#remoting

Comment: @DanielA.White, you should have put it as an the answer! Thanks!